# How to group objects by date in Realm in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, realm

I have a Realm object with a date field (a timestamp) and some other values. I want to show users all of the records for each date in a section in a UITableView. I figure one possibility is to add another field to the schema like dateString and have "September 30, 2017", etc. and query by this new field.

I'm hoping to do this without creating an additional field. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using relation for grouping Realm objects. So you can add a new class to group the object instead add a new field. The new class has a timestamp and `List` of the object. When you add the object, you also add the class for grouping. You can more easy to fetch sectioned data structure, just fetch the new class.